# Google RSS API Charset UTF-8

Tags: javascript, utf-8, character-encoding, rss, google-api

I want to use non-english characters on my jquery mobile app and I want to apply UTF-8 Charset to the result returned from Google RSS API. I searched on many sites but I could not find correct answer. I think the charset applied for the Google rss results is not correct ( I checked and it shows null) and thats why I cannot see non-english characters.

Please see below code -

```
           $.ajax({
            url: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/xxxxxxxxx,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (d) {

                _execute();
                },
```

or Is there any way to apply UTF-8 charset to javascript string/array?

Comment: So are you getting back `null` from the request or is a object property coming up as `null`?  What does the `_execute()` do? Also check your URL's correct.

Comment: URL is striped. URL is correct bcz I get english results correctly but gets garbage characters when expecting for hindi characters.  Also I checked content type using function                success: function (d,status,xhr) {
                 
                 alert(xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type"));
                 
                    _execute();
                }

Comment: Yes I am getting null in the alert box. Either the value is null or xhr object is null.

Comment: It shows blank value for xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()

Comment: I'm seriously unable to reproduce this, going to maktoob.yahoo.com, including jQuery then using `$.ajax('http://maktoob.yahoo.com',{success:function(a,b,c){console.log(a,b,c);console.log(c.getAllResponseHeaders(),c.getResponseHeader('content-type'));}});` works fine.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38319/discussion-between-jasper-and-qantas-94-heavy)

Comment: This may help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147511/corrupted-utf-8-encoding-when-reading-google-feed-alerts