# Corrupted UTF-8 encoding when reading Google feed / alerts

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, google-api, google-alerts

Whenever I try to read a Google alert via *PHP* using something like:

```
$feed = file_get_contents("http://www.google.com/alerts/feeds/01445174399729103044/950192755411504138");
```

Regardless of whether I save the `$feed` to a file or `echo` the result to the output, all `utf-8` unicode characters *(* ***i.e.*** *those with diacritics)* are represented by white space. I have tried - without success - various combinations of:

- `utf8_encode`
- `utf8_decode`
- `iconv`
- `mb_convert_encoding`

I think the wrong characters have come from the stream, but I'm lost because if I try this *URI* in a browser then everything is fine.  Can anyone shed some light on the issue?

Comment: The feed is already `utf-8` encoded, what [character-set are you specifying in your response / meta](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4279282/set-http-header-to-utf-8-using-php)?

Comment: The stream comes from Google. I save the string ($feed) directly to disk as a plain text file. There are no utf8 chars left. I tried it on different servers. Please try it too. Thanks.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do? If you are simply copying the feed verbatim and dumping the result into a file then you shouldn't need to do anything with the string. *PHP* won't care about the data that is simply *"passing through"* - it sounds more like you are having an issue with the application that you are using to view that text file afterwards.

Comment: The encodings and decodings were the desperate attempt to solve the problem. I use a coding text editor to view the file. Did you try it too? I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, you are absolutely correct - there ***is*** something untoward happening!  Though it is not what you would first suspect... For reference, given that:

```php
echo mb_detect_encoding($feed); // prints: ASCII
```

The unicode data is lost **before it is even sent** by the remote server - it appears that Google is looking at the `user-agent` string in the request header - which is non-existent using `file_get_contents` by default without a stream-context.

Because it cannot identify the client making the request it defaults to and forces [*ASCII*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) encoding.  This is presumably a necessary fallback in the event of some kind of cataclysmic cock-up. <sup>[citation needed...]</sup>

It's not simply enough to name your application however, you need to include a known vendor.  I 'm unsure of the full extent of this but I believe most folks include *"Mozilla [version]*" to work around the issue, for example:

```php
$url = 'http://www.google.com/...';

$feed = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create([
    'http' => [
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => 'Accept-Charset: UTF-8' ."\r\n"
                   .'User-Agent: (Mozilla/5.0 compatible) MyFeedReader/1.0'
    ]
]));

file_put_contents('test.txt', $feed); // should now work as expected
```

Comment: You are a hero! Thank you very much. :)